# For which $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\frac{dxdy}{\left(1+x^{2}+xy+y^{2}\right)^{\alpha}}$ converges/diverges?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

Im looking for which $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\frac{dxdy}{\left(1+x^{2}+xy+y^{2}\right)^{\alpha}}$
converges/diverges.

What I was looking for is an appropriate change of variables. I tried
polar coordinates $\left(x,y\right)=T\left(r,\theta\right)=\left(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta\right)$.
So $\left|J_{T}\left(r,\theta\right)\right|=r$ and $T^{-1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2}\right)=\left\{ \left(r,\theta\right)\mid r>0\:,\:0<\theta<2\pi\right\} $
up to a null set. So
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\frac{dxdy}{\left(1+x^{2}+xy+y^{2}\right)^{\alpha}}=\int_{T^{-1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2}\right)}\frac{rdrd\theta}{\left(1+r^{2}+r^{2}\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)^{\alpha}}=\int_{T^{-1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2}\right)}\frac{2rdrd\theta}{\left(2+r^{2}\left(2+\sin2\theta\right)\right)^{\alpha}}
$$
Then with another change of variables $t=r^{2}$ we get that $dt=2rdr$
and so I got
$$
\int\frac{dtd\theta}{\left(2+t\left(2+\sin2\theta\right)\right)^{\alpha}}
$$
Questions:

1. Does it help somehow?
2. Is there a better change of variables here?
3. How can I find the range of $\alpha$ that im looking for?
4. Is it possible maybe to block the function with and easier one to integral and then use sandwich?

Comment: Since the integrand is asymptotic to $r^{-2 \alpha}$, you have convergence whenever $- 2 \alpha < -1$, i.e. for $\alpha >1$.

Comment: Is there a way to actually compute the integral?

Comment: @Crostul There is a factor of $r^{2}$ coming in when you switch to polar coordinates.

Comment: @Jon Explicit computation of  integral may not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

First note that if the integral over one of the four quadrants converge then the integral over the whole plane converges. [Use the transformations $x \to -x$ and $y \to -y$ for this]. So integrate over $x,y>0$ Note that $x^{2}+xy+y^{2} \geq x^{2}+y^{2}$ and $x^{2}+xy+y^{2} \leq 2(x^{2}+y^{2})$ since $2xy \leq x^{2}+y^{2}$. Now using polar coordinates you see that the integral converges iff $\frac {r} {r^{2\alpha}}$ is integrable near $\infty$ which is true iff $\alpha >1$. Note: I have used the inequalities above just to get rid of $\sin (\theta)$ and $\cos (\theta)$. When you have a function of $r$ alone it is easy to see when the integral converges.

Comment: The Jacobian of the polar transformation is $r$, not $r^2$. Then we integrate $d\theta$, a fixed total angle - it should be $\frac{r}{r^{2\alpha}}$ we're testing for integrability at $\infty$.

Comment: @jmerry Thanks for the correction. I have edited my answer.